# always view dialog in landscape

Tags: android, dialog, orientation

I'm repeating a post I've made at the android group in google groups (http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/78d0b7496a51e3b7# ), hopefully I'll have some luck here!

I have an activity displaying a list of items. Upon clicking an item, 
I display a full-screen dialog with some buttons and an image. This 
looks great in landscape, but doesn't look good in portrait (Due to 
the image aspect ratio). I would like to know if its possible to 
always display this dialog in landscape irrespective of current screen 
orientation. And after the dialog is dismissed, I'll handover the 
orientation back to the sensor. Here's what I have so far:

```
OnItemClickListener listlistener = new OnItemClickListener() { 
                @Override 
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View arg1, int position, 
                                long arg3) { 
                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getParent()); 
                        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                        final int orientation = 
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation; 
                        if (orientation == 1){ 
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
                        } 
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog); 
                        dialog.setCancelable(true); 
                        ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.img); //A 
static image for testing UI 
                        //BUTTON LISTENERS HERE 
                        dialog.show(); 
                        dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() { 
                                @Override 
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) { 
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR); 
                                } 
                        }); 
                } 
        };
```

But by doing so, the screen changes orientation first and then tries 
to display the dialog. But on orientation change the screen is 
restarting the activity and my dialog isn't shown. Is there a simpler 
way to do this? Could I use two different layout for the dialog and 
load a corresponding one depending on the orientation? If so, then 
what would the XML for the portrait mode  look like? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom layout for the dialog, just design a new one and put it in the layout-land folder (create it if necesary), that way it will load the corresponding one automatically.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't explained clearly. When the user clicks on an item, I want the dialog box to open up in full screen in landscape EVEN if the current orientation is portrait. How do I load the dialog box this way? Since the length of my image is always greater than its height, loading the dialog in portrait mode creates a lot of empty space above and below the image.

Comment: I would find a way to make it work in both layout, however, if you want to do what you want to do, use a static boolean variable, that gets evaluated during onCreate, and depending on its value it fires the dialog. That way the code you have will work, even though the activity is getting recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rotate your top view 
`android:rotation="90`" *in XML*
  or
`constraintNumber.rotation = 90f` *programmatically*.

Then you don't need to change activity orientation, which can lead to some other issues.

If you have a background for your screen then you can add background to the top view group and then add rotation for rotation to the child view group. Because the rotation will work for the background as well.

For example:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_blue_24dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:rotation="90"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

<!--          Your views-->
            
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```